# Trying to bind in ng-init a value. This value was set afler model loading, and 2 ajax calls

Tags: angularjs

I explain myself,

The application i'm making right now come from a derivative of phonegap. I must absolutely waiting ajax answer to set de ng-init. I know i can do something like this ng-init = "ng-model = arr[0]" or i can use a variable for le position of the array like ng-init = "ng-model = arr[position]". That is simple in most case, but me because i'm working on a derivative phonegap i must call my function from a focus method with an ajax call, plus waiting after the result of another ajax call. See what i mean:

HTML select code:

```
<select id="usSelect" class="geotabFormEditField" ng-init="usCycle = usCyclesArr[usPos]" ng-model="usCycle" ng-options="x.descEn for x in usCyclesArr" ng-change="usSel()"}></select>
```

Function where i call my angular function to define which option must be selected. I must absolutely call it in this function.

```
focus: function (freshApi, freshState) {
    freshApi.getSession(session => {
        database = session.database;
        freshApi.call('Get', {
            typeName: 'User',
            search: {
                name: session.userName
            }
        }, function(user){
            lang = user[0].language;
            glScope.getHosRules(database);
        }, function(){
            //Oops can't get user
        });
    });
},
```

function called is getHosRule.

The angular array:

```
     $scope.usCyclesArr = [{cycleId: 'America8Day', descEn: 'USA Property 70-hour/8-day', descFr: 'Propriété É.-U. 70 heures/8 jours'}, {cycleId: 'America7Day', descEn: 'USA Property 60-hour/7-day', descFr: 'Propriété É.-U. 60 heures/7 jours'}, {cycleId: 'America7DayBig', descEn: 'USA Property 60-hour/7-day (16-hour exemption)', descFr: 'Propriété É.-U. 60 heures/7 jours (exemption de 16 heures)'}, {cycleId: 'America7DayNo34h', descEn: 'USA Property 60-hour/7-day without 34-hour reset', descFr: ''}, ...];
```

function to get which option must be selected:

```
$scope.getHosRules = function(dat) {
    console.log(dat, url);

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $scope.urlPath + 'borderCross/' + dat + '/getHosRules',
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    }).then(function successCall(response) {
        //console.log(response.data);

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.usCyclesArr.length; i++) {
            //console.log($scope.usCyclesArr[i].cycleId);
            if($scope.usCyclesArr[i].cycleId === response.data[0].us_id) {
                $scope.usPos = i;
            }
        }

    }, function errorCall() {
        console.log('Unexpected error');
    });
}
```

The problem is usPos get is value after ng-model is loaded and i must waiting for ajax answer, so it desn't working. I tried ng-init="{{usCycle = usCyclesArr[usPos]}}" It seem working but an error appear in the console and i can't take the risk on a professional app. So Anybody knows how can i bind usPos variable ?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way myself and it's simple. Refreshing my ng-model with the simple code below and removing ng-init attribute in html file.

```
$scope.usCycle = $scope.usCyclesArr[$scope.usPos];
```

Dropdown take right position.

Of course like Vivek said, breaking the loop when position is found is better.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, you need to set the value of `$scope.usCycle` which will be shown as the selected value of dropdown.

Rather than setting the value in `ng-init`, why are you not setting in `for` loop:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < $scope.usCyclesArr.length; i++) {
        //console.log($scope.usCyclesArr[i].cycleId);
        if($scope.usCyclesArr[i].cycleId === response.data[0].us_id) {
            $scope.usCycle = usCyclesArr[i]; // <-- directly assigning value
        }
    }
```

Few points I would like to highlight:

1. You are facing issues because your `ng-init` works with AngularJS lifecycle where as your Business logic is triggered from `focus` function which is not at all connected with AngularJS. So, its a bad choice to mix code like this. To provide better UX, you can use **spinner** to make the user wait unless the `$scope.usCycle` value is assigned.
2. Rather than iterating through entire loop of `for(var i = 0; i < $scope.usCyclesArr.length; i++)` , you can `break` [break the loop once you find the value](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_break). It will save extra looping cycles.